# Java Exceptions. Cast one type to another

Tags: java, exception

Could someone explain why the first cast does not give a CCE ?

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    Test.<RuntimeException>throwIt(new Exception());
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private static <T extends Throwable> void throwIt(Throwable throwable) throws T {
    throw (T) throwable; // no ClassCastException
    throw (RuntimeException) throwable; // ClassCastException(as it should be)
  }
}
```

P.S. Comment one cast (otherwise it won't compile).

Comment: The second `throw` is unreachable

Comment: What is your question? Is your code compiling? You will get Unreachable code compilation error.

Comment: oh, common, comment one then the other

Comment: Exception is the super class and you cannot cast it to RuntimeException

Comment: What specifically dont you understand?

Comment: "as it should be" is the one I understand, the other is the question

Comment: I can tell you that the generic parameter type is erased when the code is compiled. At runtime there isn't even a cast. Won't post an answer until I can find the corresponding JLS section to verify why this is valid behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the feature of Java generics realization, it was realized through type erasure, that's why (T) cast actually cast it to Throwable as leftmost bound. Because, new Exception() produces a Throwable object you can safely throw it.

You can check it in JSL
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/typesValues.html#108979